# Catching a 413 Request Entity Too Large in Django

Tags: django

When uploading a file, how can I catch the 413 Request Entity Too Large error so I can reload the form with a message saying the file is too large? I've already increased the limit in NGINX with `client_max_body_size` so this is a fallback in case someone still does exceed the limit.

Comment: What do you mean by catch it with Django, is JavaScript handling your upload?

Comment: Not at the moment but I'm flexible. I can use React instead of using Django Templates.